# For counting permutations with identical objects, why does dividing nPr by the factorial of the number of identical objects give the correct answer?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I can find plenty of sites that *say* that this works, but I can't seem to find an explanation for *why* it works. I'm rather stumped.

Comment: So we aren't precisely dividing by the factorial of the number of identical objects, but dividing by iPi where i is the number of identical objects?

Comment: I was already aware that i! = iPi, but I hadn't made the connection that that was why we were dividing by i!. That was my issue. Thanks!

Comment: It's like the shortcut for counting a herd of cattle: count the legs and divide by four.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you have n positions need to be filled by n items divided into m categories. Items in the same category are non-distinguishable. Let $x_1,x_2,...x_m$ denote number of items in each category, so you have $n=x_1+x_2+...+x_m$.

There are $n\choose x_1$ ways to choose positions for items in category 1.

There are ${n-x_1\choose x_2}$ ways to choose positions for items in category 2.

There are ${n-x_1-x_2\choose x_3}$ ways to choose positions for items in category 3.

...

Finally there are ${n-x_1-x_2...-x_{m-1}\choose x_m}$ ways to choose positions for items in category m.

Number of ways of permutation should be: ${n\choose x_1}\times {n-x_1\choose x_2}\times {n-x_1-x_2\choose x_3} \times \cdots \times{n-x_1-x_2...-x_{m-1}\choose x_m}=\frac{n!}{x_1!\times(n-x_1)!}\times \frac{(n-x_1)!}{x_2!\times(n-x_1-x_2)!}\times \frac{(n-x_1-x_2)!}{x_3!\times(n-x_1-x_2-x_3)!}\times\frac{(n-x_1-x_2..-x_{m-1})!}{x_m!\times0!}=\frac{n!}{x_1!\times x_2!\times...x_m!}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\blacksquare$

Comment: One quibble:  There should be some dots between the $\binom{n - x_1 - x_2}{x_3}$ term and the $\binom{n - x_1 - x_2 - \cdots - x_{m - 1}}{x_m}$ term to indicate the pattern continues.  You can use the \cdots command to achieve this.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig fixed that. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Logical Answer:**

Assume, **n** is the number of identical objects.
Dividing by **n!** is like saying that we are dividing by all the possible arrangements that might have occurred but they did not as the objects are identical. So, dividing by n! essentially rules out all such possibilities that did not exist.

Comment: I think this answer is better than the accepted answer in some ways and worse in another. 
 Better because it attempts to answer the original question directly, and better because it is based on a sound combinatorial insight.  Worse because it is borderline incomprehensible, and hence totally unconvincing. The accepted answer is better pedagogically: everyone loves "proof" by example, and such a "proof" might predispose a reader to discover a correct proof for themself later on.